# ES2015 ${ } syntax apply toString() on a Buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, buffer

seems like in ES2015, Template String `${ }` syntax will apply `toString()` to a Buffer object

```
let a = Buffer.from('hello')

let b = () => {
    console.log(`es6 : ${a}`) // hello
    console.log('raw a : ', a) // <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f>
    console.log('compiled to es5 : ' + a) // hello 
    console.log(+a) // NaN
}

b()
```

I can't find enough information on this topic, can anyone explain this ?

Comment: Isn't `.toString()` applied when concatenating *any* object with a string? Isn't that the logical thing to do when building a string? (What else would you want it to do?)

Comment: thanks, I don't really understand that under the hook.
so the only problem left is ${} syntax

Comment: In your edited question, the template string version logs a single string value to the console (where that string is the result of evaluating the template syntax), but the next line logs two separate values to the console without concatenating anything, so I'm not sure why you are comparing them.

Comment: nnnnnn is correct. `console.log(\`es6 : ${a}\`)` is equivalent to `console.log("es6 : " + a)`. `console.log('es5 : ', a)` will print the raw value of `a` and is not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${}` syntax causes to invoke `toString` method on any js object:

```js
let a = {toString: ()=>("I'm a string")};
console.log(`result: ${a}`);
```

Comment: thank you, very interesting ! I found that by using babel : `console.log(`${b}`)`  will become `console.log('' + b)` in es5, which explains everything.